# Don't truncate query results in the console

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I made this query:

```
query = from i in MyApp.Image, where: i.deleted_at >= ^Timex.beginning_of_day(date), where: i.deleted_at <= ^Timex.end_of_day(date), select: i.path, order_by: [asc: i.deleted_at]
```

and when I call the query:

```
MyApp.Repo.all(query)
```

I get 62 results but it will truncate them after the first 50 results to `...` for the remaining records:

Last of 50 results.

```
"images/8a3ded267cbb45cc848032c826453c8.png", ...]
```

Is there a way I can tell elixir/ecto to not truncate the results?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Execute this from `iex` or put it into `.iex.exs` file in the project directory:

```rb
IEx.configure(inspect: [limit: :infinity])
```

More info on [`Configuring the Shell`](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html#module-configuring-the-shell).